# Adding Navigation Bar items to secondary view in IB

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I work on an application that presents a UINavigationController-based interface with a root view and a secondary view. On the root view, I have configured the left and right buttons to two toolbar buttons.

I would like to configure the navigation bar items on the secondary view in a similar way. I know that it can be done with some coding (and so I have done...), but my question is if it is possible to do in Interface Builder?

I tried to drag items to the simulated Navigation bar, but it does not work (the items are simply rejected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that the view controller for the second view was separate from the view, connected by outlets. The UINavigationItem should be dragged to the controller, not the view, which was my mistake.

I hope this helps someone.